# Java Semaphore Stop Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, semaphore

Good afternoon all,

I'm working with Java's semaphore and concurrency for a school project and had a few questions regarding how it works!

If there are no permits available, I need the thread to exit the "queue" - not just sleep until one is ready. Is this possible? As you can see in my `try, catch, finally` - there is no handle for this event:

```
try {
    semaphore.acquire();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " aquired for 3 seconds " + semaphore.toString());
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
} finally {   
   semaphore.release();
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " released " + semaphore.toString());
}
```

Daniel brought up the `tryAquire` function - this looks great but the tutorials I have read state that semaphores require a `try, catch, finally` block to prevent a *deadlock*. My current code (implementing `tryAquire`) will release in the `finally` block even if that thread was never acquired. Do you have any suggestions?

```
public void seatCustomer(int numBurritos) {
    try {
        if(semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " aquired for 3 seconds " + semaphore.toString());
            Thread.sleep(3000); 
        } else {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " left due to full shop");
        }

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {   
       semaphore.release();
       System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " released " + semaphore.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read the JavaDocs for [Semaphor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).  In particular, look at the tryAcquire method.

> Acquires a permit from this semaphore, only if one is available at the time of invocation.
>
> Acquires a permit, if one is available and returns immediately, with the value true, reducing the number of available permits by one.
>
> If no permit is available then this method will return immediately with the value false.

What this means is you can try to acquire a permit if any are available. If none are available, this method returns false immediately instead of blocking.

You'll have to make your "finally" block a little smarter.

```
boolean hasPermit = false;
try {
    hasPermit = semaphore.tryAcquire();
    if (hasPermit) {
        // do stuff.
    }
} finally {
    if (hasPermit) {
       semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! That is what I have been playing with but my try/catch/finally blocks release threads that were never acquired =/

Comment: I've updated my answer to include how to handle it in your finally block.

Comment: That's the ticket--really appreciate all your help @Daniel